# Erro após atualizar Android Studio e Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Boa noite pessoal, meu projeto estava tudo normal, e eu fui viajar e fiquei 1 semana fora!
Cheguei hoje e tive que atualizar o android studio e o flutter e após isso estou recebendo um erro que não consigo resolver por nada!!!

Após eu tentar rodar meu app o seguinte erro aparece...

> Note: C:\Users\ERIK MENDES\Desktop\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:unchecked for details.

E eu já não sei o que fazer, meu projeto já está rodando em multidex, eu simplesmente estou perdido!!

Comment: Tenta dar um `flutter clean` e depois `flutter pub get`... Se não resolver adicione mais detalhes a pergunta, qual versão do Flutter você tem, o projeto compila e roda com esse erro ou simplesmente não compila?

Comment: Cara isso é um erro ou um warning?? Se não me engano em um projeto meu isso ocorre e é apenas um warning, toda a aplicação funciona perfeitamente... Analise melhor sua dúvida, se for realmente um warning, basta que você atualize teu package e ajustes os outros (As vezes um package pode ter incompatibilidade com versões de outros packages). Não se esqueça de configurar teu projeto igual é ensinado ao criar teu projeto Firebase.

Comment: Então rapaziada, o problema é que realmente nao roda o projeto, achei que fosse apenas um erro de indexação do android studio, apaguei a pasta .idea e .iml e iniciei novamente mas também não resolveu, mas quando rodo o app no projeto android inves de projeto flutter, ele compila normal, ja reinstalei o flutter e o android studio, mas o erro permanece :(
Mesmo quando eu crio um projeto novo com o app exemplo padrao do flutter ele também não compila

Comment: Se você cria um projeto novo e tenta compilar, ele te da o mesmo erro? Você já mudou a `minsdkversion` do projeto?

Comment: Ja resolvi formatando o pc kkk mas vlw rapaziada